# How to compare dates in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I'm trying to make a library/book tracking app which tracks the date and returns the status like its returned or lost etc. I need to compare dates in my app but i can't find how to in Vue.js.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  window.vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: '',
      enterdate: '',
      items: [{
        name: '',
      }]
    },
    methods: {
      addRow() {
        this.items.push({
          name: this.message,
          date: this.enterdate
        })
      },
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="message" required placeholder="Enter Name">
  <input type="date" v-model="enterdate" placeholder="Enter Date">
  <table border="1" v-for="item in items">
    <tr>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.date}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button @click="addRow">Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap your date string into `new Date()` and compare as follows `new Date(this.enterdate) < new Date()` Check the snippet as well.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: '',
    enterdate: '',
    items: [{
      name: '',
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    addRow() {
      if (new Date(this.enterdate) < new Date()) {
        alert("Today or Past date");
      } else {
        alert("Future date");
      }
      this.items.push({
        name: this.message,
        date: this.enterdate,

      })
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="newVue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model="message" required placeholder="Enter Name">
    <input type="date" v-model="enterdate" placeholder="Enter Date">
    <table border="1" v-for="item in items">
      <tr>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.date}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button @click="addRow">Add</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have dates represented as strings. Then to compare it you need to parse it first. I would recommend you to take some existing library for this. http://momentjs.com/ is a good example.

Then you would do something like:

```
dateA = moment(itemA.date, "MM-DD-YYYY"); // replace format by your one
dateB = moment(itemB.date, "MM-DD-YYYY");

if (dateA.diff(dateB) > 0) {
     // do something if A is later than B
} else {
     // do something if B is later that A
}
```

Comment: Moment is huge, don't use it please! It takes more space than vue + vuex + vue-router in total. It's huge overhead for your app to use it just to compare dates. Try to use https://date-fns.org/ or https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs instead

Comment: dayjs is good choose and have the same api as momment js 

`dayjs(dateInStr, format) < dayjs(otherDateInStr, format)`

Comment: As i said moment is just an example. As starting point it's completely ok. Depending on your needs you can replace it to whatever.